# jpa primary key violation when persisting many-to-many  columns 

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

My entities are:
the ID of device  which is deiveID
has many-to-many relationship with 
the ID of Lib   which is rID

my test code is :
two new device entities want to set the same new libentity

the problem is :
if i use the same entitymanager to persist that 2 new device entities, it will be ok.
but if i use 2 different entitymanager instance to persist them ,the error"primary key violation" will come out. I think the entitymanger try to persist the libentity at the second time, which has already been persisted in the first time.

--------------deviceinfo entity ------------------------------------------------

```
@Entity
@Table(name="deviceInfo")
public class DeviceInfoEntity extends BaseEntity implements Serializable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long deviceId;
....
@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "device_lib", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "deviceInfo_id",
  referencedColumnName="deviceId"), 
  inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "lib_id", referencedColumnName="rId"))
private List<LibEntity> resourceList = null;
......
}
```

-------------------------lib entity ---------------------------------------------

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="lib")
    public class LibEntity extends BaseEntity implements Serializable{
           @Id
       @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
       private long rId;

          @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "resourceList", cascade=CascadeType.ALL,
                  fetch=FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity=DeviceInfoEntity.class)
       private List<DeviceInfoEntity> deviceInfolist = null;

           .....
    }
```

my test code is:

```
EntityManagerFactory emFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("testPU");
          EntityManager em = emFactory.createEntityManager();


    LibEntity libEntity = new LibEntity();


    DeviceInfoEntity dEntity = new DeviceInfoEntity();
    dEntity.setName("dadadada");
    dEntity.setLibEntity(libEntity);


    DeviceInfoEntity dEntity2 = new DeviceInfoEntity();
    dEntity2.setName("dadadadadddddd");
    dEntity2.setLibEntity(libEntity);


    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.persist(dEntity);
    em.getTransaction().commit();

    em.close();

    EntityManager em2 = emFactory.createEntityManager();
    em2.getTransaction().begin();
    em2.persist(dEntity2);
    em2.getTransaction().commit();
```

it will have the error:

```
 Unique index or primary key violation: "PRIMARY KEY ON PUBLIC.LIB(RID)"; SQL statement:
 INSERT INTO lib (RID) VALUES (?) [23505-165]
```

but if i use the same EntityManager the error will not happen. Is there anyone know whats the reason? is that caused by `cascade=CascadeType.ALL`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JPA cascade persist and references to detached entities throws PersistentObjectException. Why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4294671/jpa-cascade-persist-and-references-to-detached-entities-throws-persistentobjecte)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are corrupting your persistence context by assign detached objects to managed objects.  Managed object should only reference other managed objects.

For dEntity2 you should set the libEntity to the result of a find(), getReference() or merge() of libEntity.

i.e.

```
dEntity2.setLibEntity(em2.find(libEntity.getClass(), libEntity.getId());
```

You could probably also call merge() instead of persist() and it should resolve the detached objects.