# Problems with em.persist on new entity with existing but detached OneToOne entity

Tags: hibernate, jpa, persistence

I use Hibernate on JBoss AS 7.1 and have problems when i create new entities and set an existing entity to a ManyToOne relation. The exising entity (customer) is queried before using the following code:

```
TypedQuery<Customer> query = em.createNamedQuery("Customer.findByLastNameLike", Customer.class);
query.setParameter("lastName", "%"+lastName+"%");
return query.getResultList();
```

When i execute an `em.persist(order)` on the new entity `order` after setting `customer` to order with `order.setCustomer(customer)` the following exception is thrown:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: erp.model.persons.Customer
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:717)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:710)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.EJB3CascadingAction$1.cascade(EJB3CascadingAction.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:380)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:323)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:165)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeBeforeSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:437)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:266)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3PersistEventListener.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:151)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:725)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:701)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:705)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:853)
```

The entities are defined as follows:

```
@Entity
public class Order extends AbstractEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8061887078955032972L;

    @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.PERSIST}, optional = false)
    private Customer customer = null;

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("customer")
public class Customer extends Person implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2788107135840578322L;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="customer")
    private List<Order> orders = null;
```

What is wrong in this scenario?

Thanks for any hint...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441598/detached-entity-passed-to-persist-error-with-jpa-ejb-code will help.

Comment: i think these answers are not related to my problem. i have an existing detatched entity (customer1), which is set to a ManyToOne relation (customer) on a new created entity (order1). I think this is a quite common usecase. When i em.persist(order1) because i have no id set in order1, then Hibernate complains when it wants to persist customer1.

Comment: Do you set your customer1 to order1 as well?

Comment: i already said this in my initial answer and today i clarified this more precisely...
and, as i used Glassfish with its EclipseLink before, there were no issues with this ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following answers answer my question as well. i changed from using `em.persist()` to `em.merge()` even for new entities. And now my whole object graph is persisted sucessfully, whether there are new entities mixed in or not.

[JPA cascade persist and references to detached entities throws PersistentObjectException. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4294671/jpa-cascade-persist-and-references-to-detached-entities-throws-persistentobjecte)

And furthermore i removed `CascadeType.PERSIST`