# When calling persist(): "uninitialized proxy passed to persist()"

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

When calling EntityManager.persist(), I get an error:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: uninitialized proxy passed to persist()
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:630)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:219)
        at fr.u2m.dao.jpa.GenericDaoJPAImpl.persist(GenericDaoJPAImpl.java:60)
        at fr.u2m.exposium.cms.service.dao.AdminServiceDAO.creerSiteProd(AdminServiceDAO.java:1047)
        at fr.u2m.exposium.cms.service.AdminService.enregistrerSiteProd(AdminService.java:731)
        at fr.u2m.exposium.cms.action.AdminAction.sauverPublication(AdminAction.java:673)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.dispatchMethod(DispatchAction.java:270)
        at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.execute(DispatchAction.java:187)
        at fr.u2m.exposium.cms.action.AdminAction.execute(AdminAction.java:1458)
        at fr.u2m.struts.OpenViewRequestProcessor.processJpaActionPerform(OpenViewRequestProcessor.java:270)
        at fr.u2m.struts.OpenViewRequestProcessor.processActionPerform(OpenViewRequestProcessor.java:115)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
        at fr.u2m.struts.OpenViewRequestProcessor.process(OpenViewRequestProcessor.java:230)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at fr.u2m.viparis.cms.filter.MultiTabSessionFilter.doFilter(MultiTabSessionFilter.java:75)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at fr.u2m.viparis.cms.filter.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:54)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at fr.u2m.viparis.cms.util.auditing.AuditingFilter.doFilter(AuditingFilter.java:44)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at fr.u2m.util.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:71)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:581)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:200)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: uninitialized proxy passed to persist()
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:61)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:609)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:601)
        at org.hibernate.engine.EJB3CascadingAction$1.cascade(EJB3CascadingAction.java:30)
        at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:268)
        at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:216)
        at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:169)
        at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:130)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeBeforeSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:431)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:265)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:181)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:121)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3PersistEventListener.java:49)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:131)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:87)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:609)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:601)
        at org.hibernate.engine.EJB3CascadingAction$1.cascade(EJB3CascadingAction.java:30)
        at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:268)
        at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:216)
        at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:169)
        at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:296)
        at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:242)
        at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:219)
        at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:169)
        at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:130)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:456)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:334)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:181)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:121)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3PersistEventListener.java:49)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:131)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:87)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:609)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:601)
        at org.hibernate.engine.EJB3CascadingAction$1.cascade(EJB3CascadingAction.java:30)
        at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:268)
        at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:216)
        at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:169)
        at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:130)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeBeforeSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:431)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:265)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:181)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:121)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3PersistEventListener.java:49)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:131)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:87)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:38)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:618)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:592)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:596)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:213)
        ... 59 more
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: uninitialized proxy passed to persist()
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:630)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:219)
        at fr.u2m.dao.jpa.GenericDaoJPAImpl.persist(GenericDaoJPAImpl.java:60)
        at fr.u2m.exposium.cms.service.dao.AdminServiceDAO.creerSiteProd(AdminServiceDAO.java:1047)
        at fr.u2m.exposium.cms.service.AdminService.enregistrerSiteProd(AdminService.java:731)
        at fr.u2m.exposium.cms.action.AdminAction.sauverPublication(AdminAction.java:673)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.dispatchMethod(DispatchAction.java:270)
        at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.execute(DispatchAction.java:187)
        at fr.u2m.exposium.cms.action.AdminAction.execute(AdminAction.java:1458)
        at fr.u2m.struts.OpenViewRequestProcessor.processJpaActionPerform(OpenViewRequestProcessor.java:270)
        at fr.u2m.struts.OpenViewRequestProcessor.processActionPerform(OpenViewRequestProcessor.java:115)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
        at fr.u2m.struts.OpenViewRequestProcessor.process(OpenViewRequestProcessor.java:230)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at fr.u2m.viparis.cms.filter.MultiTabSessionFilter.doFilter(MultiTabSessionFilter.java:75)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at fr.u2m.viparis.cms.filter.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:54)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at fr.u2m.viparis.cms.util.auditing.AuditingFilter.doFilter(AuditingFilter.java:44)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at fr.u2m.util.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:71)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:581)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:200)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: uninitialized proxy passed to persist()
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:61)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:609)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:601)
        at org.hibernate.engine.EJB3CascadingAction$1.cascade(EJB3CascadingAction.java:30)
        at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:268)
        at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:216)
        at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:169)
        at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:130)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeBeforeSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:431)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:265)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:181)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:121)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3PersistEventListener.java:49)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:131)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:87)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:609)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:601)
        at org.hibernate.engine.EJB3CascadingAction$1.cascade(EJB3CascadingAction.java:30)
        at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:268)
        at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:216)
        at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:169)
        at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:296)
        at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:242)
        at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:219)
        at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:169)
        at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:130)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:456)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:334)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:181)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:121)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3PersistEventListener.java:49)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:131)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:87)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:609)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:601)
        at org.hibernate.engine.EJB3CascadingAction$1.cascade(EJB3CascadingAction.java:30)
        at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:268)
        at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:216)
        at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:169)
        at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:130)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeBeforeSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:431)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:265)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:181)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:121)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3PersistEventListener.java:49)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:131)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:87)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:38)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:618)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:592)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:596)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:213)
        ... 59 more
```

Obviously, something goes wrong in the `DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist()`. I persist a Website entity, and this exception is thrown if the LazyInitializer associated to the entity is unintialized.

http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/hibernate/hibernate/3.1/hibernate-3.1-sources.jar!/org/hibernate/event/def/DefaultPersistEventListener.java?format=ok

I have no idea why this happens. Any idea?

Edit:

In my web.xml, I have an hibernateFilter:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>sessionFactoryBeanName</param-name>
        <param-value>sessionFactoryAdmin</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>flushMode</param-name>
        <param-value>AUTO</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: How you crate the entity? Do you have some code snapshot so we can reproduce it too?

Comment: @rbalent: problem is, I don't know where to look. I could paste the line with the persist() call, but what's the point? The whole app is thousands of lines of code so I could hardly copy everything and I doubt anybody would want to read that amount of code...

Comment: It seems the problem came from corrupt test data, even if I still can't figure out why. Anyway, the problem is solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to add the OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter from spring in your web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>entityManagerFactoryBeanName</param-name>
        <param-value>entityManagerFactory</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: I already have an hibernateFilter. I will add the part to the question. Problem is: the application is using the Hibernate API on some places, and the JPA API on others.

Comment: Could you try merge() instead of persist() ? see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4294671/jpa-cascade-persist-and-references-to-detached-entities-throws-persistentobjecte